# trying to get Salary for months March to December then add them up in mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql

```
$January = 'January';
$February = 'February';
$March = 'March';
$April = 'April';
$May = 'May';
$June = 'June';
$July = 'July';
$August = 'August';
$September = 'September';
$October = 'October';
$November = 'November';
$December = 'December';
$user = $_COOKIE['user'];
$Year = '2017';
$Year1 = '2016';
```

in the below code i am trying only to get the Salary field with their values were the months are from March to December but it returns null but in the database i can see there are values in the Salary field .

```
// total Salary 
$result1 = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT Salary FROM $tb2_name WHERE Employee_Number='$user' AND Month='$March' AND Month='$April' AND Month='$May' AND Month='$June' AND Month='$July' AND Month='$August' AND Month='$September' AND Month='$October' AND Month='$November' AND Month='$December' AND Year='$Year1' "); 

$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1); 

$test_sum = array_sum($row);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your query to the following

```
     $result1 = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT Salary FROM $tb2_name WHERE Employee_Number='".$user."' AND ( Month='".$March."' OR Month='".$April."' OR Month='".$May."' OR Month='".$June."' OR Month='".$July."' OR Month='".$August."' OR Month='".$September."' OR Month='".$October."' OR Month='".$November."' OR Month='".$December."') AND Year='".$Year1."' ");                                             


while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)){
        print_r($row);
    }
```

Comment: Should add escaping. `$_COOKIE['user']` is not safe.

Comment: this does not select all but only one month

Comment: i have updated my answer , you have to use a loop to get all records

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it would be a good idea to change the design of your database table to actually hold a date (like a [DATE or DATETIME data type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html)), that would simplify your query to this:

```
SELECT Salary FROM $tb2_name
WHERE Employee_Number='$user'
AND `date` BETWEEN '2016-03-01' AND '2016-12-31'
```

That would give you all the rows for employee `$user` between the 1st of March and the 31st of December of 2016. So, if you have the freedom to alter the table, I'd highly advise you to do so.

That being said. The main problem with your current query is that you're using `AND` instead of `OR`. A salary row in your database can never have the month March AND April AND May (etc.) at the same time. It's always one or the other.

But with so many months, using a lot of `OR` statements can become hard to read (and might cause problems when mixing it with other `AND` or `OR` statements). In that case you can also use the `IN` statement to have the column match anything in that group of choices. So change it to:

```
SELECT Salary FROM $tb2_name
WHERE Employee_Number='$user'
AND Month IN (
    '$March', '$April', '$May', '$June', '$July', '$August',
    '$September', '$October', '$November', '$December'
)
AND Year='$Year1';
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this one:

```
$result1 = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT Salary FROM $tb2_name WHERE Employee_Number='mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$user)' AND (Month='$March' OR Month='$April' OR Month='$May' OR Month='$June' OR Month='$July' OR Month='$August' OR Month='$September' OR Month='$October' OR Month='$November' OR Month='$December') AND Year='$Year1' ");
```

Comment: Should add escaping. `$_COOKIE['user']` is not safe.

Answer (score 0):

use OR condition

```
$result1 = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT Salary FROM $tb2_name WHERE Employee_Number='$user' AND Month='$March' OR Month='$April' OR Month='$May' OR Month='$June' OR Month='$July' OR Month='$August' OR Month='$September' OR Month='$October' OR Month='$November' OR Month='$December' OR Year='$Year1' "); $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1); $test_sum = array_sum($row);
```

Comment: Problem: bad mix of AND and OR

Answer (score 0):

```
$result1 = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT Salary FROM $tb2_name WHERE Employee_Number='".$user."' AND ( Month='$March' OR Month='".$April."' OR Month='".$May."' OR Month='".$June."' OR Month='".$July."' OR Month='".$August."' OR Month='".$September."' OR Month='".$October."' OR Month='".$November."' OR Month='".$December."') AND Year='".$Year1."' ");
```

Answer (score 0):

To match any of the values of a list, you can use `IN` statement to form a more compact query.

```
SELECT salary FROM tablename WHERE colname IN('value1', 'value2', 'value3', ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

**use ENUM for month like below**

```
create table income(id int not null primary key auto_increment,
user_id not null varchar(500),
month ENUM('Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'),
year varchar(500),
salary varchar(500))
```

**Query**

```
SELECT salary FROM income
WHERE month in('Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec') 
and user_id='user_01'
```